# Automatically click the refresh button in Salesforce lightning

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

This is the code for the mentioned button that refreshes the selected salesforce view:

```html
<div class="slds-button-group">
  <lightning-button-icon class="forceRefreshButton rotate">
    <button name="refreshButton" title="Refresh" type="button" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border-filled">
      <lightning-primitive-icon>
         <svg focusable="false" data-key="refresh" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 52 52" class="slds-button__icon">
          <g>
            <path d="M46.5 4h-3c-.8 0-1.5.7-1.5 1.5v7c0 .9-.5 1.3-1.2.7-.3-.4-.6-.7-1-1-5-5-12-7.1-19.2-5.7-2.5.5-4.9 1.5-7 2.9-6.1 4-9.6 10.5-9.7 17.5-.1 5.4 2 10.8 5.8 14.7 4 4.2 9.4 6.5 15.2 6.5 5.1 0 9.9-1.8 13.7-5 .7-.6.7-1.6.1-2.2l-2.1-2.1c-.5-.5-1.4-.6-2-.1-3.6 3-8.5 4.2-13.4 3-1.3-.3-2.6-.9-3.8-1.6C11.7 36.6 9 30 10.6 23.4c.3-1.3.9-2.6 1.6-3.8C15 14.7 19.9 12 25.1 12c4 0 7.8 1.6 10.6 4.4.5.4.9.9 1.2 1.4.3.8-.4 1.2-1.3 1.2h-7c-.8 0-1.5.7-1.5 1.5v3.1c0 .8.6 1.4 1.4 1.4h18.3c.7 0 1.3-.6 1.3-1.3V5.5C48 4.7 47.3 4 46.5 4z">
            </path>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </lightning-primitive-icon>
      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Refresh</span>
    </button>
  </lightning-button-icon>
</div>
```

The code I am using is:

```
setTimeout(autorefresh, 60000);
    
function autorefresh() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("forceRefreshButton").click();
        setTimeout(autorefresh, 60000);
    }
    
autorefresh();
```

The function should run every 60 seconds and click on the refresh view button. But it seems that I can't get the correct element.

Code overview:
[image: Code overview]

Comment: 1. Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) for this. 2. [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an object, not an element. You can't call `.click()` on that. Instead, you can do `[...document.getElementsByClassName("forceRefreshButton")].forEach(button => button.click());`

Comment: Thx for the reply.

The setInterval works (tested it with the console.log() function. But the clicking doesn't function. 

I added in the original question a code screenshot if it gives a better overview.

Comment: The function does not work. Should I look in some other parts of the page source for the button code ? As i understand it, when inspecting the button element this is the source that represents the refresh button.

Comment: The button will be first clicked after 60 seconds. If you want the first execution to happen immediately, call `autorefresh()` before the `setInterval()` line.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), so that the button is clicked repeatedly.
2. [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an `HTMLCollection`, not an `Element`, therefore you can't call `.click()` on it.
3. Call `.click()` on a button, `.forceRefreshButton` is not a `<button>` element.

```js
function autorefresh() {
    document.querySelector('.forceRefreshButton > button').click();
}

setInterval(autorefresh, 60000);
```